# AJAX, Image from file to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to place all images contained in an image folder, and pass them all into an array. Have went through a few similar questions on stackoverflow, and I've become a bit stumped at this point.

```
var folder = "images/";

$.ajax({
    url: folder,
    success:function(data){
        function(i,val){
            if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ){
                var arr = [folder + val + ","];
                console.log('contents of array' + arr);
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: you need to use php for that. i think you want to scan a folder and place all file names into an array? isn't it?

Comment: That's correct, but it can most definitely be done via AJAX/JS only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First in you program function(i, val) has error

it should be `data.forEach(function(i,val))`

and from server get the response as list of files inside images/. then your can iterate through them using your code.
like hostname/images/ request should give response as

```
['img1.jpg','img2.png'] as json
```

or

you can convert all the images in server as base64 and send it back as array of string.